# What are the severity levels for service incident messages in Office365

Tags: office365, office365api

I am using service communications API (GetMessages operation) to monitor the service incident messages.
In the JSON responses, I get a property called Severity. May I know what are the different severity levels that are available and what do they signify? I've seen "Sev1", "Sev2" and "Normal" severities so far.